# $\liminf_{\epsilon\to 0} \frac{f(\epsilon)}{\epsilon}$ finite implies $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} f(\epsilon)=0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a non negative real function.

**Question:** Is it true that if $\liminf_{\epsilon\to 0} \frac{f(\epsilon)}{\epsilon}$ exists finite than necessarily $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} f(\epsilon)=0$ ?

Comment: Ok it is false. Sorry I would like to delete the post, but I do not know how to do it.

Comment: Let y = x+1, then lim inf{ \epsilon to 0} f(\epsilon)/\epsilon = 1, which shows that lim {\epsilon to 0} f(\epsilon) = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for any $x_n \to 0$,

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if } x = x_n \\ \text{anything }\ge 0 &\text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$

satisfies

$$\liminf_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{f(\epsilon)}{\epsilon}  =0.$$